# angular 6 unit testing Forkjoin service response

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular6, karma-jasmine

i have a function in service in which i have 3 http get calls and i return the response with forkJoin making an array, how will i test this service funtcion in spec.ts ?
this is the function in my registration component which is calling the service,

```
this.register.registrationData()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.types = data[0];
    this.modules = data[1];
    this.packages = data[2];
  });
```

and this is my registration service function,

```
registrationData(): Observable<any> {
    const companyTypes =this.http.get(ConstantService.apiRoutes.companyTypes);
    const modules = this.http.get(ConstantService.apiRoutes.modules);
    const packages = this.http.get(ConstantService.apiRoutes.packages);
    return forkJoin([companyTypes, modules, packages]);
}
```

this is my spec file so far,

```
 it('Should require registration data', () => {
  loginRegService.registrationData().subscribe((data) => {
    expect(data).toEqual(regData);
  })
  const reqCompany = httpTestingController.expectOne(`${environment.apiUrl}/anonymous/companyTypes/`);
  const reqModule = httpTestingController.expectOne(`${environment.apiUrl}/anonymous/modules/`);
  const reqPackage = httpTestingController.expectOne(`${environment.apiUrl}/anonymous/packages/`);
  expect(reqCompany.request.method).toBe('GET');
  expect(reqModule.request.method).toBe('GET');
  expect(reqPackage.request.method).toBe('GET');
  const e1 = forkJoin([reqCompany, reqModule, reqPackage]);
  reqCompany.flush(companyType);
  reqModule.flush(modules);
  reqPackage.flush(packages);
});
```

Comment: `expect(data.result[0]).toEqual(regData);, expect(data.result[1]).toEqual(regData);,  expect(data.result[2]).toEqual(regData);` you tried?

Comment: yes i did try this out and i changed my data accordingly to data and now its working fine ,`let regData = [companyType, modules, packages];`

Answer (score 0):

In your approach to testing this, you are mocking up HTTP observables - which is a good way to test HTTP calls in Angular.

However if you are looking for a more generic way of testing [rxjs, you can use their marbles library](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles).

In fact I wrote an [example using forkJoin which you can find here](https://github.com/hevans90/ng-test-material/blob/master/rxjs-examples/function-examples.spec.ts#L27).